# Risk around "Allow log on locally" for Domain Service Accounts

Tags: windows, access-control, group-policy

My organisation mandated that Windows Domain Service accounts internally should not have the "Allow log on locally" permission, and essentially be non-interactive.

What exactly is the potential risk for enabling this policy for a service account? Microsoft documentation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/allow-log-on-locally) states that "*unauthorized users could download and run malicious software to elevate their privileges*", I'm not sure if I understand how this is applicable.

Can someone please elaborate on the potential attack paths if this is enabled for both an internal and external facing application?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to give specifics of attack paths with the limited information you have provided, however The documentation you cite [states](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/allow-log-on-locally):

> **Vulnerability**
>
> Any account with the Allow log on locally user right can log on to the console of the device. If you do not restrict this user right to legitimate users who must log on to the console of the computer, unauthorized users could download and run malicious software to elevate their privileges.

Applications are usually run using a `Service` account, as you pointed out in your question. These accounts usually have very restricted privileges that enable them to run the application and that is it. By enabling this feature, these accounts would be able to run an interactive shell (i.e. the Command Prompt). Using the command prompt, as stated, can allow a user to download and run malicious software.

There are a multitude of ways that a malicious actor can get a shell using an application, so without any specifics (other then you have a Windows Environment), it would be hard to comment on attack vectors.

One example could be: if the application in question has an upload feature, that then hosts the document on the web-server, an attacker could upload a malicious aspx page that gives them a shell (see example [here](https://packetstormsecurity.com/files/60858/aspxshell.aspx.txt.html)). Then using this shell they could download and install malware, if the "*Allow log on locally*" permission is granted to that service account.

Comment: If "Allow log on locally" is disabled for a particular service account, would that mean it is impossible to get a shell for that account via any attack vector like the aspx one you suggested?